# How to get every paths from a list string for a tree structure which have exactly one branch in between two nodes c#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

I have a List input

```
List<string> input = new List<string>(){
1_2
5_3
2_5
4_2
};
```

> Please check the attachment below
>   [image: Sample Graph]

I need to find all paths like

```
1_2
1_2_4
1_2_5
1_2_5_3
2_4
2_5
2_3
4_2_5
4_2_5_3
3_5
```

Please give me a solution with a very fast search algorithm with c#.

*The Output should not contain same path for an example 1_2 & 2_1 it must be a anyone of those but not both of them*

Comment: This looks like homework....

Comment: This is not a homework I have created the image and question to learn a algorithm.please try to give me an answer if you can.

Answer (score -3):

You input and picture do not agree.  It looks like your inputs are parent-child so 4_2 should be 2_4.  I shouldn't be doing homework, but did any way.  I assumed there are no loops so I didn't need to use Dijkstra's algorithm.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> inputs = new List<string>(){"1_2", "5_3", "2_5", "2_4"};
            Node.CreateTree(inputs);
            Node.Print();
        }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public static Node root;

        public static Dictionary<int, Node> nodes = null;

        public int name { get; set; }
        public Node parent = null;
        public Boolean visited = false;
        public Boolean leafVisited = false;
        public List<Node> neighbors { get; set; }

        public static void CreateTree(List<string> inputs)
        {
            //assume no loops
            Dictionary<int, List<int>> orderedPathsDict = inputs.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '_' }).Select(y => int.Parse(y)))
                .GroupBy(x => x.First(), y => y.Last())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
            Node childNode = null;
            //create Nodes
            nodes = orderedPathsDict.GroupBy(x => x.Key, y => new Node() { name = y.Key }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
            //create Tree from dictionary
            //parent is key of dictionary
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int,List<int>> parentChild in orderedPathsDict)
            {
                Node parent = nodes[parentChild.Key];
                foreach (int child in parentChild.Value)
                {
                    //check if child is in list of Nodes
                    if (nodes.ContainsKey(child))
                    {
                        childNode = nodes[child];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        childNode = new Node() { name = child }; 
                        nodes.Add(child,childNode);
                    }
                    if (parent.neighbors == null) parent.neighbors = new List<Node>();

                    parent.neighbors.Add(childNode);
                    childNode.parent = parent;
                }
            }

            //get root which is the node with no parent
            root = nodes.Where(x => x.Value.parent == null).FirstOrDefault().Value;

        }
        public static void Print()
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int,Node> node in nodes)
            {
                Boolean leaf = node.Value.neighbors == null ? true : false;
                if (leaf)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Node> n in nodes) { n.Value.visited = false; }
                    node.Value.visited = true; PrintRecursive(node.Value, node.Key.ToString(), leaf);
                    PrintRecursive(node.Value, node.Key.ToString(), leaf);
                    node.Value.leafVisited = true;
                }
                if (!leaf | (leaf & (node.Value.leafVisited == false)))
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Node> n in nodes) { n.Value.visited = false; }
                    PrintRecursive(node.Value, node.Key.ToString(), leaf);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void PrintRecursive(Node parent, string ancestors, Boolean leaf)
        {
            string newAncestors = "";
            if (parent.neighbors != null)
            {
                foreach (Node neighbor in parent.neighbors)
                {
                    //do not go back on same path that you enter node
                    if (!leaf )
                    {
                        newAncestors = ancestors + "_" + neighbor.name.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(newAncestors);
                        PrintRecursive(neighbor, newAncestors, leaf);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if((parent != null) & (parent.parent != null))
                        {
                            if (!neighbor.visited)
                            {
                                neighbor.visited = true;
                                newAncestors = ancestors + "_" + neighbor.name.ToString();
                                if (neighbor.neighbors == null)
                                {
                                    if (!neighbor.leafVisited)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(newAncestors);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(newAncestors);
                                    PrintRecursive(neighbor, newAncestors, leaf);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (leaf)
            {
                if (parent.parent != null)
                {
                    parent.parent.visited = true;                    
                    newAncestors = ancestors + "_" + parent.parent.name.ToString();
                    PrintRecursive(parent.parent, newAncestors, leaf);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the trick it's not static the input can be parent child or child parent

Comment: The input simply means there is a branch between two nodes. There is no parent child concept. Each one can be parent each one can be child.

Comment: Do you care if the results contains 1_2 or 2_1?  Depending on which node is the root you will get different results.  Without knowing the root your results can be different.  The only way of finding the root is knowing the parent child relationship.

Comment: Please take a pen and paper and draw it on a paper just write the numbers as a node and join them they should give the same image. There is no root . The input is denoting that there is one branch between two nodes. Any way thanks for your answer . Please try to solve this.

Comment: Please try to use string split not char. Otherwise if there will be like 12_3 then it could cause problem.

Comment: The split is correct.  The character indicates only the '_' character.  I understand the one branch.  What the issue is if you want the output to be 2_4 or 4_2?  You said you only wanted one of the two pairs, but which one first?

Comment: output can be anything but your output is not correct as it returning 8 output where the actual one is 10

Comment: missing outputs are 5_2_4,3_5_2_4

Comment: You have 2_3 in your list which doesn't exist.  The Issue is with 4_2_5.  the problem is getting a fast algorithm that includes this node only once.  That is one reason I used a parent/child.  I can add the path.  But then the algorithm speed increase significantly.  right now I have neighbors as only children.  I would have to make neighbors both parent and child. Then get all paths which would double the paths.  Then write an algorithm to sort (so you don't have 1_2_4 and 4_2_1) and remove duplicates.

Comment: Ok please make a change for the best result

Comment: I figured out the trick.  Nodes 3 & 4 are leaves and leaves have to be handled differently.

Comment: Can you please make a change in your code to handle that?

Comment: Modified code.  Can't guarantee it will work under every condition.  It doesn't print node 2_3 which I think is wrong in your expected output.